# DrawText doesn't work, but Graphics::DrawString is ok

Tags: graphics, drawstring, drawtext

I am creating a bitmap in the memory which combine with an image and text. My code is:

```
HDC hdcWindow = GetDC();
HDC hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
HBITMAP hbmDrag = NULL;

if (!hdcMemDC) {
   ReleaseDC(hdcWindow);
   return NULL;
}

RECT clientRect = {0};
GetClientRect(&clientRect);
hbmDrag = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, 256, 256);
if(hbmDrag) {
   SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmDrag);
   FillRect(hdcMemDC, &clientRect, mSelectedBkgndBrush);
   Graphics graphics(hdcMemDC);
   // Draw the icon
   graphics.DrawImage(mImage, 100, 100, 50, 50);
#if 1
   CRect desktopLabelRect(0, y, clientRect.right, y);
   HFONT desktopFont = mNameLabel.GetFont();
   HGDIOBJ oldFont = SelectObject(hdcMemDC, desktopFont);
   SetTextColor(hdcMemDC, RGB(255,0,0));
   DrawText(hdcMemDC, mName, -1, desktopLabelRect, DT_CENTER | DT_END_ELLIPSIS | DT_CALCRECT);
#else
   // Set font
   Font font(hdcMemDC, mNameLabel.GetFont());
   // Set RECT
   int y = DEFAULT_ICON_HEIGHT + mMargin;
   RectF layoutRect(0, y, clientRect.right, y);
   // Set display format
   StringFormat format;
   format.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
   // Set brush
   SolidBrush blackBrush(Color(255, 0, 0, 0));
   // Draw the label
   int labelWide = DEFAULT_ICON_WIDTH + mMargin;
   CString labelName = GetLayOutLabelName(hdcMemDC, labelWide, mName);
   graphics.DrawString(labelName, -1, &font, layoutRect, &format, &blackBrush);
#endif
}

DeleteDC(hdcMemDC);
ReleaseDC(hdcWindow);

return hbmDrag;
```

The image can be outputted to the bitmap success.
For the text, if I use "DrawText", it can't be shown in the bitmap although the return value is correct;
But Graphics::DrawString can output the text success.

I don't know the reason. Anybody can pls tell me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `DT_CALCRECT` flag to [DrawText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498.aspx). This flag is documented as (emphasis mine):

> Determines the width and height of the rectangle. If there are
>   multiple lines of text, `DrawText` uses the width of the rectangle
>   pointed to by the *lpRect* parameter and extends the base of the
>   rectangle to bound the last line of text. If the largest word is wider
>   than the rectangle, the width is expanded. If the text is less than
>   the width of the rectangle, the width is reduced. If there is only one
>   line of text, `DrawText` modifies the right side of the rectangle so
>   that it bounds the last character in the line. In either case,
>   `DrawText` returns the height of the formatted text **but does not draw
>   the text**.

Comment: Thanks your comments. But it still doesn't work even I removed "DT_CALCRECT" or increased the width and height of the lpRect passed to DrawText.

Comment: To my surprise, DrawText can work in the WM_SIZE handler. But in the WM_SIZE handler, I passed a window DC to DrawText instead of the one created by CreateCompatibleDC.

Comment: Ah, I have found the root cause. As you said, if I pass DT_CALCRECT to DrawText without enghou width or height, it will return the RECT instead of output the text. So I should call DrawText twice. Thanks your remind.